# Count word matches between two variables

Tags: r, string

Assume two datasets A and B:

```
X1<- c('a', 'b','c')
place<-c('andes','brooklyn', 'comorin')
A<-data.frame(X1,place)

X2<-c('a','a','a','b','c','c','d')
place2<-c('andes','alamo','andes','brooklyn','comorin','camden','dover')
B<-data.frame(X2,place2)
```

I want to count how many times each word in `A$place` occurs in `B$place2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

A %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(n = sum(place == B$place2)) %>% 
  ungroup

#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   X1    place        n
#>   <chr> <chr>    <int>
#> 1 a     andes        2
#> 2 b     brooklyn     1
#> 3 c     comorin      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str_detect` from the `stringr` package.

```
library(stringr)
sapply(A$place, function(x) sum(str_detect(x, B$place2)))
```

```
andes brooklyn  comorin 
       2        1        1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
table(B$place2[B$place2 %in% A$place])

# andes brooklyn  comorin 
#     2        1        1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R version of user438383's answer.

```
sapply(A$place, function(y) sum(grepl(y, B$place2)))  

   andes brooklyn  comorin 
       2        1        1
```

The key functionality is `sapply()` which repeats an operation over all elements of a vector, `grepl()` which checks the matches and generates `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and `sum()`. When you sum a logical vector, you get the count of `TRUE`.